# mongoengine get values from list of embedded documents

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, mongoengine

Given several hundred documents with the following structure (below), what is the best way to generate a list of [date, value] for a specific parameter x?

```
 {_id: ObjectId(...),
    date: 2014-12-04 21:25:43,
    values: [
        {   parameter: ObjectId(...),
            value: 34.5
        },  
        {   parameter: ObjectId(...),
            value: 1.3
        }, 
        {   parameter: ObjectId(...),
            value: 2.0
        }, ...

    ]
}
```

Here is my progress so far:

1. Get all documents containing the specific parameter.

   ```
   parameter = Parameter.objects.get_or_404(id = args.get('parameter'))
   data = Record.objects(values__parameter = parameter).all()
   ```
2. Convert to list. This way seems terribly inefficient. If anyone has a better way of doing this please let me know!

   ```
   list = [] 
   for i in data:
       for index, item in enumerate(i.values):
           if item['parameter'] == parameter:
               list.append({'date': i.date, 'value': item['value']})
   ```

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach is to use the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to just get the matching parameters directly:

```
Record._get_collection().aggregate([
    { "$match": { "values.parameter": parameter } },
    { "$unwind": "$values" },
    { "$match": { "values.parameter": parameter } }
])
```

Or possibly a bit more efficient if you can:

```
Record._get_collection().aggregate([
    { "$match": { "values.parameter": parameter } },
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": [
            { "$eq": [{ "$ifNull": [ "$parameter", parameter ] }, parameter ] },
           "$$DESCEND",
           "$$PRUNE"
        ]
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$values" }  
])
```

Both effectively "de-normalize" the array via [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) into individual documents and "filter" that list for just the matching elements for you to process. The [**`$redact`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) allows the elements to be "pruned" from the array before you denormalize, which saves a bit of space and is generally more efficient than filtering after array elements that do not match has been de-normalized.

You could also if you wish add a [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) at the end of the aggregation pipeline there to just restrict the result fields to the ones you want:

```
    { "$project": { "_id": 0, "date": 1, "value": "$values.value" } }
```

And that may save you a little on what transfers back to your application from the server as well as removing the need to manipulate the result in code.

The `._get_collection()` there is an undocument way to access the raw [collection object](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html) from the underlying pymongo driver. This in turn allows access to the [`.aggregate()`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate) method there. All objects are plain python objects returned within a plain list.